# How to use UserName and Password in Swagger to generate Bearer Token for .NET Web API

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, swagger, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on .NET CORE 5 Web API solution and have configure Azure Active Directory for authentication. I have swagger that I need to configure take UserName and Password to generate Bearer token and then authenticate. I have implemented following code but I am not prompt for username and password in swagger for authentication?

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "APIs", Version = "v2" });
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "JWT Authorization Header Using The Bearer Schema",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            });
            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {new OpenApiSecurityScheme{Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Id = "Bearer",
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                }}, new List<string>()}
            });
        });
```

`swagger`

[image]

'Web API Endpoint`

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class SiteController : ControllerBase
{

 [HttpGet("GetSecureMessage")]
 public ActionResult<TestMessage> GetSecureMessage()
 {
        var result = new TestMessage()
        {
            GivenName = "Kim",
            ReturnMessage = "Site@ Hello, Welcome to Digital World"
        };

        return result;
    }
```

I want to provide username and password in swagger!

Comment: This is not supported: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5441

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, [Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen) for your comment. Making it is an answer to help other community member.

The above solution you are looking for it is not supported as of now.  you have to authorizing manually and pasting apiKey JWT token by hand.

From below picture it show you have to manually pass the username and password in JSON format. there will be no prompt for username and password.

[image]

Reference: https://ppolyzos.com/2017/10/30/add-jwt-bearer-authorization-to-swagger-and-asp-net-core/